# How do I define the message I want to respond to after an error is produced?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Right now, I am trying to create a mini system that will detect and respond to errors coming from incorrect command usage. But, I cannot define the message that has caused the error. What do I need to do to correctly define the message that caused the error that the system has detected? Or, if I am totally doing this wrong, what would be the correct way to complete this task?

So far, when I run my code I get an error, specifically an UnHandledPromiseRejection error, stating that 'message' is not defined. The code is in my index.js file, and the commands are in a separate folder inside the same directory as my index.js file. I have tried multiple ways of trying to define the message. I have moved the piece of code to different spots, and have even tried putting an if statement into it, and inserting it into all of the commands.

Here is the code I have in my index.js file.

```
bot.on('error', () => {
        console.log(error);
        message.reply("error message here")
    }
```

And here is the code that I have inside of all of the command files.

```
if(error) {
console.log(error);
message.reply("error message here")
}
    }
```

My expected results are to have the code detect the error, print it to the console, and send a message to the channel the command was used in, tagging the user that send it by replying to it. This message will eventually become a rich presence once I have this basic version sorted out for right now.

I think I may be doing this wrong though, so please correct me if I am. Also, note that all of the commands are inside of an async function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea to attach an error event listener to your Discord client, but you're not emitting it when you encounter an error. You'll also need to pass the message as a parameter when doing so.

```js
/* index.js */
bot.on('error', (err, message) => {
  console.error();
  message.reply('❌ Uh oh! I ran into an error.');
});
```

```js
/* commandname.js */
message.reply('if this promise is rejected, we catch it below and emit our error event')
.catch(err => bot.emit('error', err, message));
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `/home/ubuntu/commands/ban.js:26
.catch(err => bot.emit('error', err, message));
^`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the rest.

`/home/ubuntu/commands/ban.js:26
.catch(err => bot.emit('error', err, message));
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at jsfile.forEach (/home/ubuntu/index.js:36:17)`

Comment: @Sbss1111 What's the line before the one the error's pointing to?

Comment: `banChannel.send(banEmbed);`

Comment: @Sbss1111 Removing the semicolon will resolve the error - it should always go after the last `.catch` or `.then`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'll let you know if I have any more issues, but for now, it is working. Thanks for also correcting me on the semi colons.

Comment: Make sure that the method returns a promise (or it's after a `.then()`), and make sure there's no semicolon before the period.